# Updating record in Datagrid using Ajax and codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am new to Ajax.I have a data grid with large number of drop down lists .I want to update my database on drop down selection using Ajax.
Is there anyway i could update my database whenever i choose/select a value from drop down menu without page refresh using Ajax??My page looks like this:
[image]

The  demo or link of tutorial for this,would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Javascript onchange event to fire the code, more about it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Here is a basic example of AJAX:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

And more like you were asking for:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp